# MySQL - IF in a SELECT for multiple row column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `products` that holds all the products e.g T-Shirt and `product_variants` that have the associated variants of the colors, eg. Black, Blue, Green which each has a `stock` column - that holds the number of stocks left.

I would like to build a query that can tell me which of the products that are totally sold out, and which are not.

The `stock` column should be 0 to be sold out, but if its `NULL` or `> 0`, it's in stock. `NULL` is used when we have unlimited quantities.

This is the following result i would like to get:

```
product_id|soldOut|stock
------------------
1         |Yes    |0
2         |Yes    |0
3         |No     |NULL
4         |No     |1
```

What i tried to do, is the following:

1. Grab all products
2. Make a join to product_variants
3. Group by product_id to only show one result per product.
4. SELECTing product_id and `IF(stock > 0 OR stock IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') as SoldOUt`

Query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, IF(pv.stock > 0 OR pv.stock IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') as SoldOUt
FROM products p
JOIN product_variants pv ON (`pv`.`product_id` = `p`.`product_id`)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

The results is that `soldOut` is not correct - it seems like it just takes a random row of the variants and check the `stock` of this and answers.

Instead, It should check all of the variants row and see if any of them is not yet soldOut (with the if statement above) and then return one final answer for that product.

What have I done wrong and how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need a `join`, just aggregation.

So, here is one method that checks that all variants are `0`:

```
select pv.product_id,
       (case when sum(pv.stock = 0) = count(*) then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as SoldOut
from product_variants pv 
group by p.product_id;
```

I am guessing that you also want `sum(pv.stock)` as well for the final column.

Comment: Thank you! Gave me a new way to think.